# FTP error "530 Login authentication failed"

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

When I try to connect to my ftp server through firefox or IE I got this message:

```
530 Login authentication failed
```

Why I get this message?
User name and password are correct.

Are their any requirements that I need to do on the local machine before log into the ftp server?

I used `ftp://example.com` to log in.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make some changes in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, particularly you need to set

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

If you want to set access by default for the `/var/www` directory for local users you can do that with

```
local_root=/var/www
```

If you require a different directory you need to change `/var/www`. After making changes to `/etc/vsftpd.conf` you need to restart the vsftpd server with

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

My password had a decimal (e.g `Tomatoes.X`) --> after removing the dot(`.`) I was able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the parallel connections was limited by certain maximum number by the server, and that was actually creating this "mirror: Login failed: Login incorrect" problem.

by reducing `--parallel` number from 10 to 5, resolved the issue.

Ref: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/lftp-multiple-parallel-sessions-yield-login-incorrect-4175600147/#post5673254